# What is the difference between Parasitic Combination Inheritance and Combination Inheritance in javascript?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

The example codes of these two types of inheritance are here:

Parasitic Combination Inheritance: http://jsfiddle.net/dKKaS/

Combination Inheritance: http://jsfiddle.net/XZn3A/

Could someone tell me the difference? Thanks.

Comment: That is amazing ... if you go to google.com and search for "Parasitic Combination Inheritance" this post comes up #1, and it was just posted 15 minutes ago....

Comment: One difference is that the `constructor` for both types using parasitic are different, but for regular they both end up being `SuperType`...  other than that I'm not sure.

Comment: When you're asking questions about books, please include information about the work. It helps people help you, as well as correctly attributing the code. In this case, the examples are from *Professional JavaScript for Web Developers, Second Edition* by Nicholas C. Zakas (Wrox, 2009). The first example is on pages 179-180 and the second on pages 176-177.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that with Parasitic Combination Inheritance, the base constructor is only called once. With Combination Inheritance, the constructor gets called two times.

Comment: is there any special reason or usage to call constructor two times?

Comment: @Blake ... There is no reason to call the constructor twice. That is actually the problem Parasitic combination inheritance solves.